# Delete meta data (Information schema) in H2 data base

Tags: java, database, jdbc, h2

I am writing code in Java to build schema and populate an H2 in-memory DB
In order to test it I want to delete all data and try to rebuild it from code.

I tried deleting all data by command:

```
drop all objects
```

But I still have objects in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA folder in the H2 Console.
Is there a nice and easy command to drop ALL the information from H2?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't drop the objects from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` they are an essential part of the metadata the database needs.

Comment: thanks,so how can I reset the DB completely?

Comment: `drop all objects` will do exactly that. You can ignore the objects that are visible in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. As I said: they are an essential (internal) part of the database. Don't mess around with them

Answer (score 1):

For the H2 database, you can not drop the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and it's tables.

Those tables are not regular tables (where rows are persisted in the database files). Instead, the data is generated on demand, when querying them. (There is one exception: there are 3 tables that contain CLOB and BLOB data, but those are hidden. In future versions of H2 those tables will probably go away.)

Comment: thanks, how do you suggest to make a complete clean start after modifying the DB? Is there an easier way than deleting the file(s)?

Comment: Yes, run the statement "[drop all objects](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#drop_all_objects)".